# How to pass the id and name in another page in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, salesforce

I created the email template and i need to pass the id and name in another page.
How to pass or use value....

My email template

```js
var x={!Account.Name};
var y =  {!Account.Cust__c};
alert("'y");
```

```css
.ExternalClass {
 width: 100%;
}
.ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div {
 line-height: 100%;
}
body {
 -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
 -ms-text-size-adjust: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
table {
 border-spacing: 0;
}
table td {
 border-collapse: collapse;
}
body, #body_style {
    color: #333333;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 22px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}
body {
*width:700px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 700px\9;
}
map {
 display: inline;
}
.logo {
 padding:3px 10px 0 0;
}
.logo-txt {
 padding: 10px 5px;
}
.button a {
 display: inline-block;
 background: #006CB4;
 border: 1px solid #EAEB89;
 margin: 12px 0px 0px;
 border-radius: 2px;
 color: #FFF;
}
.button a:hover {
 background: #FE0000;
}
.main-txt {
 position: absolute;
 top: 125px;
 left: 3px;
 font-size: 31px;
}
.header {
 text-align:inherit;
}
.bg-title {
 margin: 58px auto 0;
 font-size: 24px;
}
 @media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
body {
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 100%;
}
}
 @media only screen and (max-width: 540px) {
body, table {
 width: 100%!important;
}
.logo {
 margin: 0 auto;
 border-right:0px;
 padding:5px 0 0;
 text-align:center;
}
.header {
 text-align: center;
}
.bg-title {
 margin:0 auto;
 font-size: 17px;
}
.main-txt {
 padding: 5px 0 0;
 width: 100%;
 top: 115px;
 left: 0;
 font-size: 21px;
}
.text {
 padding: 20px 0 26px;
}
.footer {
 padding: 8px 0;
}
}
 @media only screen and (max-width: 599px) {
 body[yahoo] .hide {
 display: none !important;
}
 body[yahoo] .table {
 width: 100% !important;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 mso-table-lspace: 0pt;
 mso-table-rspace: 0pt;
}
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="wraper" style="max-width:698px; margin: 0 auto;position:relative;background: #eeeeee;">
  <div style="max-width: 588px; margin: 0 auto;position:relative;">
    <div class="header" style="width: 100%;float: left;display: block;padding: 20px 0px 10px;">
     <div class="logo" style="margin: 0 auto;display: inline-block;text-align: left;padding: 0;float: left;width: 38%;"> <img src="img/logo-2.png" width="100%;" border="0" style="width: 150px;"></div>
      <div class="logo-txt" style="padding: 3px 0;display:inline-block;color: #299400;letter-spacing:0.5px;vertical-align: top;float:right;font-size: 12px;width: 62%;text-align: right;"><span><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" style="padding-right:5px;font-size:15px;"></i>India’s Largest Loan Distributor</span></div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
    <div style="position:relative;background:#fff;overflow: hidden;box-shadow: 0 0px 7px #b2b2b2;">
      <div class="bg-main" style="padding:8px 25px 0;">
      <p style="margin:15px auto; text-align:left;"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" style="color: #1bbc46;font-size:45px;"></i></p>
        <p><strong style="font-size: 14px;">Dear {!Loan__c.Customer_Name__c},{!Account.Cust__c},{!Account.Name}</strong></p>
        <p style="margin:5px 0 8px;">Thank you for choosing<strong> </strong> for fulfilling your <strong>{!Loan__c.Loan_Product__c}</strong> requirement.</p>
         <p style="margin:5px 0 8px;">This is to inform you that your <strong>{!Loan__c.Loan_Product__c}</strong> application has been disbursed by <strong>[sales manager]</strong> from <strong> {!Loan__c.Buyer__c} </strong>of amount <strong>{!Loan__c.Loan_Amount_Disbursed__c}</strong> on <strong>{!Loan__c.Disbursal_Date__c}</strong>.</p>
          <p style="margin:5px 0 8px;">We hope you had a smooth journey in getting your <strong>{!Loan__c.Loan_Product__c}</strong> requirement fulfilled.</p>
          <p style="margin:5px 0 0;">As our endeavour to continuously bring more value to you, we would appreciate if you would refer us your Friends or Family who is in need of a loan.</p> </div>
      <div style="clear:both"></div>
      <div style="margin:0 25px 20px; overflow:hidden;">
       <p style="display: block;margin:35px auto; text-align:center;"><a href="E:/Ref%20Page/sf-refer-ap.html?{!Account.Cust__c}& {!Account.LastName}" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;background: #1bbc46;padding: 11px 66px;letter-spacing:1px;color:#fff;font-size: 14px;border-radius: 3px;font-weight: 500;">REFER HERE</a> </p>
        <p style="margin:10px auto;">We thank you once again for giving us this opportunity in serving you! </p>
        <p style="margin: 10px 0;font-size: 14px;"><strong>Best Regards</strong>,<br>
        <strong style="color: #2a9500;">Team</strong> </p>
      <p style="margin: 15px auto 10px;text-align: center;border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;padding: 5px 0;"> <i style="font-size:12px;">“The purpose of human life is to serve, and to show compassion and the will to help others” <br><strong>- Albert Schweitzer</strong></i></p>
      </div>
      <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div>
  
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

how to use the cust_id and customer name in another page. When i click refer here i show another page. Ie page i want to use the cust_id and customer name value how can i pass the value...

I tried directly pass the value in url but it shows the value...i tried this following

"E:/Ref%20Page/sf-refer-ap.html?{!Account.Cust__c}& {!Account.LastName}"... Its shows the value in url. I dont want shows the value in url...

Comment: I don't know if this is the best solution for your needs, but as far as the parameters being visible in the url is concerned, you can use url encoding/decoding to hide the actual values of the parameters..

Comment: how can i encode the url???

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with this way

call this function on your first page from where you are sending values

```
function testJS() {
    var b = document.getElementById('name').value,
        url = 'here your next page url?name=' + Here Name value+'&id='+here id value;

    document.location.href = url;
}
```

on next page you can get values like this call this function on `window.onload event`

//here name is your query string name which value you want

```
    function GetQueryStringByParameter(name) {
        name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
        var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
            results = regex.exec(location.search);
        return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));

}
```

Comment: Hi nitin, How can i use id value also

Comment: dear its simple you can call this function like this var id=GetQueryStringByParameter(id); now this will give you value of your id query string and if you call var name=GetQueryStringByParameter(name); then this will give you value of your name query string variable.

Comment: hi nitin,i am directly get the id and name from the account in salesforce,this is the field name {!Account.Cust__c},{!Account.Name}. can i use inside id and name.it working i pass it directly in url but i dont want to show the value in url

Comment: dear if you are passing values as query string then you can use those values as above defined example and if you are getting values on your first page from Account.Cust__c and Account.Name then to get those values in your next page first set url = 'yourpagename?name=' + Account.Name+'&id='+Account.Cust__c; then on second page get those values as above defined in example

Comment: var b = document.getElementById('name').value, here i use like this  var b = document.getElementById('Account.Name').value, it is correct or not

Comment: but it shows the value in url how can i hide the value

Comment: it does not working..... It default take it from <p style="display: block;margin:35px auto; text-align:center;"><a href="E:/Ref%20Page/sf-refer-ap.html?{!Account.Cust__c}& {!Account.LastName}" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;background: #1bbc46;padding: 11px 66px;letter-spacing:1px;color:#fff;font-size: 14px;border-radius: 3px;font-weight: 500;">REFER HERE</a> </p>

Comment: in your href have you define any query string name?